# Encoding DBF file into 852 codepage doesn't work

Tags: c#, encoding, character-encoding, dbf, codepages

I'm having a problem with changing the codepage of a DBF file from 437
to 852.

I inspected the code that Encodes the datatable and it seems that inside the
Visual Studio it correctly encodes to 852 but after moving the encoded file
and replacing it with the original it comes back as if encoding didn't happen?
So I'm thinkinh that the code for encoding works fine, but something else is changing the file back to 437 codepage! Please help...

Sample Code:

```
DbfRecord orec = new DbfRecord(odbf.Header);
orec.AllowDecimalTruncate = true;
orec.AllowIntegerTruncate = true;

foreach (DataRow DR in EndodedDataTable.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < EndodedDataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        orec[i] = DR[i].ToString();
    }
    odbf.Write(orec, true);
}

odbf.Close();

File.Delete(OriginalFileName);
File.Move(TempFileName, OriginalFileName);
```

Method that does the encoding:

http://pastebin.com/jPqJMxen

Comment: Your sample code doesn't contain even the slightest reference to text encoding...

Comment: yes I know but the problem isn't the encoding code because it works, but the issue is File.Move(TempFileName, OriginalFileName) the file that is moved remains with 437 codepage even thought when i inspect DR via breakpoints it correctly encodes the characters to 852

Comment: the codes makes temporary dbf file "_DBFFILE" encodes it and replaces it with original "DBFFILE" but when I open the dbf file even thouh it seemed the odbf.Write(orec, true) was writing 852 codepage characters it still opens (in DBF Commander) as 437 codepage

Comment: You do realize that c# strings internally are always UTF16, right? Unless you have them as byte array, the strings will tell you nothing.

Comment: no I do not realize please elaborate

Comment: As far as I can see, your code isn't the code changing the encoding. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Encoding is how text is written to files. String objects in C# don't 'contain' an encoding of their own; they have to be able to support ALL unicode symbols. The encoding only happens when strings are written as bytes. So unless you did something like setting the encoding into that new DataTable object in advance, this code does nothing at all, except apparently converting all data to string for some reason (shouldn't there be type checking in there? Or doesn't that apply to dbf?).

Comment: That seems to be the _reader_. You need to adjust the _writer_ to solve this. And yes, you did that wrong. Your original data is already in 437, and you want to encode _to_ 852. So you need to _read_ the original bytes as 437 (since that's what they _are_), and _write_ that string back to bytes as code page 852.

Comment: Hi, the problem is solved it turns out that the method in the pastebin works perfectly, It was the extra code around it that generated the temporary dbf file and then tried to replace it with the original had some bug in it... I now used the pastebin method to work with encoded datatable and store it in an access file via SQL... so i don't use this "Sample Code:" from the question anymore. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that my method for encoding from 437 to 852 works fine but the additional code that created temporary file and moved it to original file caused a lot of confusion in the code and therefore didn't work correctly...

I ended up directly using the encoded datatable to write it into access file since that was my original intention

Method that returns datatable with codepage 852 encoding:

http://pastebin.com/jPqJMxen

~ ChenChi